# preg_replace - matching all content between two tags

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I am working with a CMS system that is insisting on putting lots of junk markup & empty tags between `</figure>` and `<figcaption>`tags.

I'm trying to use a regular expression to match & remove this junk (sadly fixing the CMS isn't possible).

I seem to have created a regex that's a bit too hungry and is also stripping the  tags.

```
$str = '<p></p><figure class="image"><img title="Screenshot 2014-08-26 16.34.12.png" alt="Screenshot 2014-08-26 16.34.12.png" src="/image/Screenshot%202014-08-26%2016.34.12.png" class="image-style-none" typeof="foaf:Image"></figure><p></p>
    <p>Â&nbsp;</p>
    <p></p><figcaption>Screenshot 2014-08-26 16.34.12.png</figcaption><p></p>
    <p>  </p>
    <p> </p>
    <p></p>';

preg_replace('#(</figure>).*?(<figcaption>)#s', '[replace-me]', $str);
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: It's probably too hungry because you're not using matching tags: `<figcaption>` goes with `</figcaption>`. Better to use those, and then simply use these tags in whatever you replace it with.

Comment: Expected outcome is as source except all tags/markup between the closing <figure> and </figcaption> should be replaced with [replace-me]

Comment: HTML is not a regex-parsable language. [*Don't use regex on HTML. Just DON'T.*](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/237955)

Comment: I completely agree but the filter hooks in this CMS sadly allow regex alterations only. Horrible proprietary system.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
preg_replace('#(?<=<\/figure>)(.*?)(?=<figcaption>)#ms', '[replace-me]', $str));
```

Aren't regular expressions just so fun!

Comment: Thank you - this works just as I needed. The other answers are all valid too by the looks, but this was first to answer my need.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a little tweak to your regex.

```
(?<=</figure>).*?(?=<figcaption>)
```

**[Working demo](http://regex101.com/r/gP0pP1/1)**

[image]

You can use above regex to match only the content and replace it with an empty string. Look at the Substitution section above.

The idea is to use regex lookaround to match the content between those tags but exclude the tags

Answer (score 2):

In the replacement string use back references to the parts in parentheses :

```
preg_replace('#(</figure>).*?(<figcaption>)#s', '$1$2', $str);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression that removes any `<p>` tags only containing spaces, non-breaking spaces, and non-ascii characters e.g.

```
$str = preg_replace('/<p>(\\s|&nbsp;|[\x80-\xFF])*<\/p>/i', '', $str);
```

Although workable in this case, it's generally frowned upon to use regular expressions to alter HTML.

Answer (score 1):

```
function getNodeContent($name, $buffer) {
    $matches = array();
    preg_match_all("/<" . $name . "[\w\s]*[^>]*>(.*?)<\/" . $name . ">/", $buffer, $matches);
    return isset($matches[1]) ? $matches[1] : '';
}

echo "<pre>";
var_dump(getNodeContent('figure', $str));
var_dump(getNodeContent('figcaption', $str));
echo "</pre>";
die();
```